# Workaround for pip install -E option

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, fabric, pip

I am running a Fabric script that sets up a virtualenv on a remote server (running Ubuntu 12.04) and installs various packages into it. The script uses the `-E` option for pip to install the packages into the virtualenv:

```
pip install -E . -r [path to requirements]
```

This used to work alright, but it appears the -E option has been removed from pip now (from the [pip changelog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)).

Can anyone please suggest a workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [explained here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/other-tools.html#using-pip-with-virtualenv), if you need to use pip to install a package in a virtualenv environment, just use the pip installed in virtualenv :

> Because pip is installed by virtualenv, just use
>   `path/to/my/environment/bin/pip` to install things into that specific
>   environment.

The pip team remove the `-E` option because pip is now bundled into every new virtualenv environment, so you can use it to install new packages.